# how to redirect error code of screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, error-code

I am running a command through screen like this:

```
screen -d -m sh -c 'command'
```

The problem is that I would like to check if the command succeeded.

It seems that I can't do this with `echo $?`.

http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?25611#postcomment

One way is to redirect the error to a file and check the file if it is empty.

```
screen -d -m sh -c 'invalid_command  2>error.txt'
```

Can you think of another way in order not to mess with files?

Comment: What about `screen -d -m sh -c 'command ; echo $?'` ?

Comment: It doesn't return anything . it seems that screen absorbs the output

Comment: Let's force output to tty ugly way: `screen -d -m sh -c 'command ; echo $? > \`tty\`'`

Comment: this doesn't work either